# match after nth occurrence in R stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

How can I match things in between the nth and n+1th occurrence of a pipe?

In the string `abc|def|ghi|jkl` I would like to match `ghi`.

My best attempt is

```
str_match_all('abc|def|ghi|jkl', '((?<=\\|)[^|]*)')[2,1]
```

but this is somewhat inefficient because it matches more than what I need, then cuts it down in R to the 2nd match. I was wondering if there was a way more native to regexp to take only the nth match.

Comment: `(?:[^|]*\|){nth}([^|]*)` then group 1

Comment: Why did you accept `r"(?<=\|)[^\|]*(?=\|)"`? It is not working in R and if used correctly in R, [does not extract `ghi`](https://regex101.com/r/BEftk2/1).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? Should capture everything between pipes.

```
r"(?<=\|)[^\|]*(?=\|)"
```

Comment: https://regexr.com/#native_link# tried it here and seems to work fine :) Have you tried it in practice yet? Weird!

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
str_extract(x, "(?<=\\|)[^|]+(?=\\|[^|]+$)")
regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=\\|)[^|]+(?=\\|[^|]+$)", x, perl=TRUE))
sub(".*\\|([^|]+)\\|[^|]+$", "\\1", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mpxwnN/1) (`str_match` / `regmatches`) and [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCK88I/1) (`sub`).

**Details**

- `(?<=\\|)` - makes sure there is a `|` char immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^|]+` - one or more chars other than `|`
- `(?=\\|[^|]+$)` - immediately to the right of the current location, there must be a `|` char, then any 0+ chars other than `|` and then the end of string.

R:

```
library(stringr)
x <- "abc|def|ghi|jkl"
str_extract(x, "(?<=\\|)[^|]+(?=\\|[^|]+$)")
## => [1] "ghi"
regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=\\|)[^|]+(?=\\|[^|]+$)", x, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "ghi"
sub(".*\\|([^|]+)\\|[^|]+$", "\\1", x)
## => [1] "ghi"
```

Comment: your first two suggestions do work, but because they still require R to "overmatch" and then subset the part I'm interested in with `[,2]` and `[[1]][2]`. for this MWE it seems trivial, but for my actual application, I would like to avoid overcreating. objects, and extract just the element I am interested in within regex. Basically avoid creating an array of results due to size, if possible!

Comment: @Lee88 You yourself used `str_match_all` and I assumed you know what you are doing. See my update. All return matches only.